# C behavior with pointer addition

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Given:

```
int a[N];
int *p;
```

why does `a-p` work yet `a+p` does not with error: "invalid operands to binary +".

Comment: What is `a` in this context ?

Comment: You only have `A` defined above though ?

Comment: @jamesdlin has now kindly fixed your mistake - please take more care when posting questions.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: Of course it matters. `A` and `a` are completely separate variable names.  If you're going to write code (and ask questions about code), you must be precise.

Comment: Not really, the question was why it doesn't even compile and rather issues an error.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: Yes, really, unless you want answers of the type "It doesn't compile because you haven't declared any variable named `a`."

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: since you hadn't even defined the type of `a` in your original question there was no way to give a specific answer - we had to guess what you really meant. Please take more care in future.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the A case, mea culpa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *difference* between two pointers is meaningful, i.e. it is the number of elements between the two pointers (provided that they both lie within the same array).

*Adding* two pointers makes no sense though (how would you interpret it ?).

Comment: Of course, in this case, `a - p` is nonsensical (and has undefined behavior), even though it's allowed.

Comment: @jamesdlin: yes, it would need to be `p - a`, and `p` would need to point at an element within `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Because subtraction makes sense, it's the distance between two pointers. Addition of pointers makes no sense.

Your array decays to a `int*` when used with the subtraction operator, and given that two pointers are (1) of the same type, (2) pointing to elements in the same array, and (b) pointer `T *b` greater than pointer `T *a`, then the standard guarantees the result of `b - a` to be the number of `T` elements between `a` and `b`.

In your case, however, the pointers do not point within the same array and therefore the result of `a - p` is undefined (even though it compiles).

(Note that the standard is a bit more specific about when and how you can subtract two pointers, but this is mainly it.)